# QtSQL error: SQLITE driver doesn't recognize my DB file as a database

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, qt, qtsql

the title mostly explains the problem.

I am using Qt 6 and the SQL module to connect to a external SQL database file (format is simply .db), in order to learn how SQL management via Qt works.

I learned a lot, but I am stuck with one last problem which prevents me to send requests and use my data : it seems like QtSQL is able to create a connection to my SQL database, but then, is FULLY UNABLE to recognize the file as a database, and makes my query unactive.

One error log from the terminal will be more useful than a whole post trying to find words so I could explain correctly the thing:

```
=> Successfully connected to DB // db.open()
ERROR: file is not a database //... isActive()
Can't execute the instruction
```

The code:

```
QSqlDatabase sqlDb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    sqlDb.setDatabaseName(m_pathToDb + "db.sql");
    if (sqlDb.open()){
        std::cout << "Successfully connected to DB" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Can't connect to SQL - " << sqlDb.lastError().text().toStdString() << std::endl;
    }

    QSqlQuery query = sqlDb.exec("SELECT * FROM table_1");

    if(!query.isActive()){
        std::cout << "ERROR: " << query.lastError().text().toStdString() << std::endl;
    } else {
        while (query.next()){
            std::cout << query.value(1).toString().toStdString() << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

I merely translated the very last line from French, so expect it to be not exactly what SQLite would've returned in English.

Oh, and yes, the m_pathToDb variable has a correct value, I checked it several times. I don't know how SQLite internally works so I am lost for now.
Thanks in advance for anyone who'll help me.

Comment: Are you sure your file is really a sqlite database file? Normally a sqlite database ends with `.sqlite` and not `.sql` - I would guess you have a simple text file with sql instructions here instead a sqlite database file.

Comment: Well, I am not an expert into SQL, so it's clearly possible. Yes, it does have mostly SQL instructions, but I didn't imagine this file could be organized another way. How could I export my DB base from .sql to .sqlite?

Comment: A text file with sql statements is **no** DB... If you want to create a sqlite database open it with Qt, parse your text file and execute the statements via QSqlQuery::exec()

Comment: So there's no way to just "connect" to the file and get my data imported from it? I remember watching examples with Qt programs using setDatabaseName() with files finishing with a .sql extension.

Comment: No - a text file with sql statements has nothing to do with sqlite. Exporting/importing from sqlite can be done e.g. as described [here](https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/sqlite/importing-and-exporting-data-in-sqlite)

Comment: Ok, I think you misunderstood my point. I was insinuating, by talking about the .sql file being a DB, that it was the main element that would recreate the DB if parsed. Nevermind anyways, I think I understood how to solve my problem. Thanks you.